# NoReverseMatch at / django python:Reverse for '*' not found. tried

Tags: django, python-3.x

Reverse for 'details' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['details/(?P[.\-\w]+)$']

I am getting this error when I open the home page. All other pages seem to work.

urls.py

```
app_name = 'main'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'ask-question/$', views.question, name='ask-question'),
    url(r'^details/(?P<slug>[.\-\w]+)$', views.details, name='details'),
]
```

views.py for the home page

```
def home(request):
    questions = Question.objects.all().order_by("-date")
    numbers = Question.objects.all().count()
    numbers2 = Answer.objects.all().count()
    total_users = User.objects.all().count()
    # counting answers on specific questions
    results = Question.objects.annotate(num_answers=Count('answer')).order_by("-date")

    # PAGINATION ===============================
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

    paginator = Paginator(results,10)
    try:
        results = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        results = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        results = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    # end of counting
    empty = []
    for a in  Answer.objects.all():
        idd = a.id
        question_id = (a.question_id)
        empty.append(str(question_id))
    repeatition = Counter(empty)
    # i = 0
    # trend_list = []
    # for x in range(len(repeatition)):
    #     new = repeatition.most_common()[i][0]
    #     trend_list.append(new)
    #     i += 1
    # if len(trend_list) != 0:
    #     trend = Question.objects.get(id=trend_list[0])
    # else:
    #     trend = 'No Trending Category'
    # getting the answers to all questions in the front page

    # search the questions ============
    query= request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        short_list = Question.objects.all()
        questions = short_list.filter(title__icontains=query)
        resulted = questions.annotate(num_answers=Count('answer'))
        counted = questions.count()
        context1 = {
            'questions': questions,
            'query': query,
            'counted': counted,
            'resulted': resulted,
        }
        return render(request, 'main/search.html',context1)
    context = {
        'questions': questions,
        'numbers': numbers,
        'numbers2': numbers2,
        'total_users': total_users,
        # 'trend': trend,
        'results': results,        
    }
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', context)
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %} {% block content %}

<div class="container">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button> {{ message }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<!-- end of the message container -->
<!-- start of the actual questions -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 class="text-left" id="brand"> Recently Added Questions</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div id="qtns">
                {% for q in results %}
                <a href="{% url 'main:details' q.slug %}" id="questions">
                    <h4 id="titleq">{{ q.title }}</h4>
                </a>
                <a href="{% url 'main:filter' q.category %}">
                    <p class="badge badge-info">{{ q.category }}</p>
                </a>
                <p id="titleq">{{ q.date |timesince }} ago. <a href="{% url 'accounts:profile' q.user %}" id="questions" style=" padding: 2px; border:1px solid orange;">{{ q.user }}</a></p>
                <div class="text-right">
                    <p>Answers: {{q.num_answers}}</p>
                </div>
                <hr> {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div id="qtns1">
                <br> {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
                <a href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}?next={% url 'main:ask-question' %}" class="btn btn-md btn-info">Ask Question</a><br><br> {% else %}
                <a href="{% url 'main:ask-question' %}" class="btn btn-md btn-warning">Ask Quesiton</a><br><br> {% endif %}

                <div class="qtns2">
                    <h1 id="titleq">Statistics</h1>
                    <p>Questions asked: {{numbers}} </p>
                    <p>Answers: {{ numbers2 }}</p>
                    <p>Total Users: {{ total_users }}</p>
                </div> <br>
                <div class="qtns2">
                    Most answered:
                    <a href="{% url 'main:details' trend.slug %}" style="text-decoration:none;">
                        <p>{{ trend }}</a> - <i>{{ trend.user }}</i></p>
                    <p><i>Posted On: </i>{{ trend.date}}</p>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="qtns2">
                    Most Questions By:
                    <a href="{% url 'accounts:profile' trend.user %}" style="text-decoration:none;">
                        <p>{{ trend.user }}</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <!-- pagination for the limited display of questions -->
    <nav aria-label='pagination'>
        {% if results.has_other_pages %}
        <ul class="pagination">
            {% if results.has_previous %}
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ results.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
            {% else %}
            <li class="page-item disabled"><span class="page-link">&laquo;</span></li>
            {% endif %} {% for i in results.paginator.page_range %} {% if results.number == i %}
            <li class=" page-item active"><span class="page-link">{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span>
            </li>
            {% else %}
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
            {% endif %} {% endfor %} {% if questions.has_next %}
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ results.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
            {% else %}
            <li class=" page-item disabled"><span class="page-link">&raquo;</span></li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

{% endif %} {% endblock %}
```

All other pages are working, but the home page is returning reverse for 'details' ..... not found. What seems to be the problem, I can't figure it out. Can anyone please look at my code and tell me my mistake. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you encounter an error you need to have a debugging strategy. In NoReverseMatch case the strategy would be:

1. Find all the cases where reverse for 'details' is called.
2. Check that cases validate by asking yourself three questions:

   - Is object in the context?
   - Is field (or key/value) you're trying to get part of this object?
   - Is value as expected?

All answers must be yes. If the answer is no, fix it.

Cases where reverse for 'details' is called are:

```
<a href="{% url 'main:details' q.slug %}" id="questions">
<a href="{% url 'main:details' trend.slug %}" style="text-decoration:none;">
```

Are `q` and `trend` in the context? `q` is as part of `results` object, that is a yes and `trend` isn't in the context, because you commented that part of the code in your views. `trend.slug` thus returns *nothing* and reverse for 'details' with *nothing* is not found, because *slug* is expected.

If you fix this, this error should go away.

Comment: thanks it worked and also thanks for  suggestions for debugging. Much appreciated